# About Fancybox and PHP Mysql

Tags: php, html

my problem is that the only first word from the database can be called in fancy box's title/caption..

here's my code

for example the name in the product_name is "Ben What"

```
                                echo '<td><li><a id="example1" href='. $row['product_image_url'] . ' title=' . $row['product_name'] .' ><img src=' . $row['product_image_url'] . ' ></img></a></li></td>';
```

if i view the Picture it will only display Ben in the Title/Caption not Ben What

is there a way that i can view the whole words??

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the value of the `title` attribute in the generated html.

```
... ' title="'.$row['product_name'].'" >' ...
```